# Android - Show/Hide Action Menu Bar in Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is my scenario: I have three fragments and I only want to show an action bar in one of those fragments. In the activity that creates the fragments, I currently have this code which correctly creates the menu bar:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_view_report, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_view_report) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewReportActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Then in one of the fragments of which I am trying to hide the menu bar I have this code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(false);
}

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_view_report).setVisible(false);
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Does anyone have any idea of what I am doing wrong or a suitable solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: getActivity().getActionBar().show();

Comment: It is showing in each of my three fragments, I need to hide them in the other two this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: well use .hide() in other two

Comment: Does this just go in the onCreate?

Comment: you can call it wherever you want

Comment: that won't work, causes my app to crash

Comment: ok send crash report also test this ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();